# how count form 0 to 18446744073709551616(2^64) in asssembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

i need to count from 0 to 18446744073709551616(2^64) in a loop.

can i use xmm regiters?

for example a thing like this

```
 MOV XMM0,0
 LABEL1:
 INC XMM0
 CMP XMM0,18446744073709551616;(2^64)=18446744073709551616
 JNE LABEL1
```

If not, what should I do?

Comment: Get a faster computer, for starters. No matter how fast your computer is, it is not fast enough.

Comment: Even if you can count 1 billion number per second, this will take almost 600 years to finish the loop. Do you REALLY need to do this?

Comment: it is not problem.problem is an other thing.

Comment: i know.just answer to me.i can wait 100000000000bilion years.

Comment: I know nothing about xmm, but you need at least 65 bits to represent all numbers from 0 to 2**64.

Comment: xmm0...xmm7:128bits registers.so i think there is no problem.

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia-article on SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Registers), the `xmm`-registers can be used to calculate with two 64 bit integers each. It seems that you won't be able to do 65 bit arithmetic without considering extra processor flags or something. I've never programmed with SIMD myself, so that's as clear as I can make it :) I *do*, however, know that you can manage arbitrary width arithmetic with the "regular" general purpose registers with help from the carry flag.

Comment: "I can wait 100000000000 billion years." Such patience. Mine runs out after 2 or 3 hundred years, and then I start to get antsy.

Comment: @KeithThompson except for using the `CF` bit of `RFLAGS` too :) (Of course, this would be a hack; but hey, you'd have to hack for 65bits anyways)

Comment: @darkness: do you actually need your counter hold the value 2^4? If not, you can do this with 2 32-bit registers (64 bits), otherwise you need 65 bits.

Comment: For interest I did some measuring, counting to 2^32 and timing it. On my machine it takes about 1.5 seconds to count straight to 2^32 and about 3 seconds if I split it up over two 16 bit registers and use `add`/`adc` like below. This seems to indicate that the total time to count to 2^64 would be around 200-400 years. FYI :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not practical. There is no realistic scenario where this program will run to completion.

Comment: Why don't use x86_64, just `inc rax` is enough. You don't need to waste time posting a question here, instead you compile it faster and go for a tea while waiting for it to count

Comment: it's not really off topic, it's always fun to spawn a counter thread and inspect how far they got at any moment. It's a great way to get a feel for threading and performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assembly is rather rusty, but you can get 96 bit (32 * 3) counting with help from `adc` (Addition with carry) something like this:

```
; Reset our "composite register" ecx:ebx:eax to 0:
  xor eax, eax
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor ecx, ecx

loop:
  add eax, 1
  adc ebx, 0 ; adds 1 to ebx if eax just overflowed, 0 otherwise
  adc ecx, 0 ; adds 1 to ecx if the previous addition overflowed

  cmp ecx, 1 ; This is true after 2^64 iterations
  jne loop
```

Comment: Now to tuck that into a little program that I can put in the real-time processing class with the highest priority... oh, wait...

Comment: Since you’ll never actually reach 2**64, you can get rid of the compare and make it an unconditional jump =)

Comment: Why 2^96? this takes 2^32 times longer than OP actually requested.  And I think the code is wrong; inc doesn't set the carry bit, you should have used "add eax, 1".  You can just do a "jnc" instead of the "cmp/jne", and now the loop will terminate :-}  And the "inc/adc ..." pair can be replaced by "add ebx,1", so now it terminates faster.  I think I've cut the overall execution time in half.   Let's unroll the loop a few times, .... oh, there's *so* many optimizations you can do to this code to speed it up ...

Comment: @IraBaxter You're right that `inc` does not update the carry flag. Thanks! Fixed :) Other than that, it's not clear why OP wants to count to 2^64, so I gave them an implementation that does exactly that. No one is claiming that this is not stupid. If they can do the `jnc` optimization and get rid of `ecx` in the calculation they are free to do so :)

Comment: @StephenCanon ...which would make his program misbehave on a later, more capable computer :) It's like relying on the memory to wrap around at the 1MB mark - as it was in the old ages.

Comment: @MagnusHoff How about using a 64bit CPU instead so you need only, say, the `RAX` register plus one bit? (despite the question mentioned x86 and not amd64)

Comment: @Powerslave I've got the impression that 32 bit mode is a limitation here. Otherwise, sure, use one general purpose 64 bit register and keep an eye on CF.

Comment: @MagnusHoff Good point. I think, as the question also has pointed out, considering the use of the XMM regs pretty much makes sense here if speed is not an issue.

Comment: You don't need a 3rd `adc` here.  Just `add` / `adc` / `jnc` to break out of the loop when the 64-bit counter produces a carry-out (i.e. when it wraps back to 0).  If the OP really wants the loop body to run with a 65 / 96-bit value for the last iteration, peel that iteration out of the main loop.  Remember, this will take hundreds of years to run, so optimization is *important*...  I think.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a 128 bit register.  Increment a 64-bit register and check for overflow.

```
       xor rax, rax
again: inc rax
       jz again ; zero flag is set on inc overflow
```

... or you could do it with loop (but loop instruction might be "slow")

```
       xor rcx, rcx
again: loop again ; ~rcx counts UP to 2^64 as rcx counts down to 0
```

... add uses more opcode space than inc but MIGHT be faster

```
        xor rax, rax
 again: add rax, 1
        jc again
```

... unroll the loop for even more speed

```
        xor rax, rax
 again: add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        add rax, 1
        jc again ; only test needed as we know final_value % 8 == 0
```

Also, each core of the cpu is always performing the function you requested from the time it boots.  You can poll its progress with the RDTSC instruction.

```
 rdtsc ; progress reported in rdx:rax
```

Everyone wants to know the point of your question.  I assume there is one because you asked it.  For those that cannot contemplate a reason:

```
  a) progress will be inspected before completion
  b) fool unreachable code "error" detection
  c) wasQuantumComputerInvented() function
  d) easier to ask than "real" question
  e) OP didn't originally realize how long it might take
  f) or simply a learning exercise
```

... but seriously, what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

```
loop:
  JMP loop
```

After ~400 years, this loop will reach 2^64.

Anyone who runs this for that long without reaching 2^64, let me know, but there have been no reports of this algorithm failing, since, for all intents and purposes, it's as useful as the accepted answer.

Comment: except if you want to add a second  thread that tells you what the current value is(via command prompt-like gui), and how many times longer it would take to reach it. Which is of educational value, I did this in C but not in assembly. 65 seconds of my program only reached 1/1877649880 of the way there(that's with 4 threads LITERALLY racing).

Comment: But not particularly interesting because OS wastes count time by task switching, C overhead, and so on... Too bad getting into 64 bit assembly real mode is such a chore to do real science. Maybe somebody older and wiser  than me can perform such a test for me.